# AWS Issue: load_dataset from S3 Fails with Unexpected Keyword Argument Error in HuggingFace

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-datasets

I'm encountering an issue with an AWS SageMaker notebook and HuggingFace's load_dataset function. I'm attempting to load a JSON file from an S3 bucket, but I'm running into an error that I can't seem to resolve.

**What I'm trying to do:** Load a JSON dataset from an S3 bucket using HuggingFace's load_dataset function.

**The Error**: When I try to execute the function, I receive the following error message: `Session.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hf'`.

**Code Snippet**:

```py
train_file_directory = "s3://dir_name/train.json"
data = load_dataset("json", data_files=train_file_directory, split="train")
```

**Environment**: I'm running this on AWS Sagemaker with Python version 3.10.13 and datasets version 2.15.0.

The dataset loaded initially without any issues, but then I upgraded the instance of the sagemaker and it has been repeatedly giving this problem since.

Comment: can you try reinstalling datasets ->  pip install datasets[s3]

Comment: @ArunLokanatha That does not seem to fix anything, I ran pip install -U datasets[s3]